# How to use "annotations" column from Spacy-annotator?

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I used `spacy-annotator` to annotate some data.
The result is a new column in the pandas DataFrame.
Does anyone know how to use that annotated data to train the `spacy` model?
Appreciate the answer.

I tried the following, but seems it needs to be in a different format:

```
TRAINED_DATA.to_csv('trained.csv', index=False, columns=['annotations'])

TRAIN_DATA = pd.read_csv('trained.csv')
```

where the `TRAINED_DATA` is the original file that i used with the spacy-annotator with the column annotations. `TRAIN_DATA` is the file training data that i want to input to the model.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `TRAIN_DATA.annotations` (after reading it as csv)? Perhaps it's now type `string` instead of `tuples`. If so convert the type by running this code:

```
TRAIN_DATA2 = []
for i in TRAIN_DATA:
    if isinstance(i, str) == True:
        i = eval(i) 
        TRAIN_DATA2.append(i)
```

`TRAIN_DATA2` is now your input file for the model.

Answer (score 0):

[spacy-annotator](https://pypi.org/project/spacy-annotator/) v2.1.2 has an option to export your data in .spacy format.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy_annotator as spa

df = pd.DataFrame({
"text": [
    "New york is lovely, Milan is nice, but london is amazing!",
    "Stockholm is too cold. Ingrid Bergman says so."
]})

# Initialise annotator
annotator = spa.Annotator(labels=["GPE", "PERSON"])

# Label data
df_labels = annotator.annotate(df=df, col_text="text")

# Export annotations to .spacy format
spacy_annotations = annotator.to_spacy(df_labels, "spacy_labels.spacy")
```

See also [spacy-annotator on GitHub](https://github.com/ieriii/spacy-annotator) for a demo and examples